# Where does MySQL "store" table overhead data?

Tags: mysql, myisam, overhead

I'm about to move a large database table away from my production server for backup.

~130,000,000 rows, 45GB total data.

After an interupted DELETE query (during the update process) the table now has an overhead of over 100MB.

From past experience I can't optimize this table on my production server without impacting on the perfromance of my live site.

So I plan to move the table to another server.... I always take the .frm, .MYD and .MYI files...

But where is the overhead stored?  In the .MYD? And do I need to bring overheard data with me if the table will need to be rebuilt anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overhead is space in the data files that used to contain data but doesn't anymore (due to `DELETE` queries etc.). If you can't optimize, you're going to be stuck transferring the overhead.